# LDAP - Directory Manager service giving, OutOfMemory

Tags: java, ldap, out-of-memory, opendj

I have a LDAP server running . The LDAP service used is of **OpenDJ** .

Whats happening is that directory manager service on that machine is going java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

On obtaining Thread Dump of Directory Manager service below is what we get

> Thread t@883: (state = BLOCKED) - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long)
>   @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise) -
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object,
>   long) @bci=26 (Compiled frame) -
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long)
>   @bci=91 (Compiled frame) -
>   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(long,
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=72 (Compiled frame) -
>   org.opends.server.extensions.TraditionalWorkQueue.retryNextOperation(org.opends.server.extensions.TraditionalWorkerThread,
>   int) @bci=128, line=452 (Compiled frame) -
>   org.opends.server.extensions.TraditionalWorkQueue.nextOperation(org.opends.server.extensions.TraditionalWorkerThread)
>   @bci=9, line=401 (Interpreted frame) -
>   org.opends.server.extensions.TraditionalWorkerThread.run() @bci=41,
>   line=149 (Interpreted frame)

Operation being performed on LDAP is read from ldap which is causing this issue.  Frequent read requests are being sent to that server.
Can anyone please tell me whats going wrong with the LDAP over here?

EDIT : **OpenDJ** version is 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

OpenDJ will produce a proper error message in the logs/errors file when the JVM is running out of memory. Most of the time, an out of memory exception is an indication of improper tuning of the JVM and OpenDJ. You will need to provide complete configuration and details of operations, as well as log files for anyone to help you troubleshoot the issue.
I suggest you bring this to the OpenDJ mailing list (opendj AT forgerock DOT org). Or you take a look at the troubleshooting and tuning sections of the Administration Guide.